# Angular 2 feed new data to already instantiated Dynamically Loaded Component

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using Dynamic Component Loader and all is working well if all data is initiated on the component initialization. I am using this code:

```
this.dcl.loadAsRoot(SomeComponent, "#somediv", this.injector).then((cmp)=>{

     // @Input()
     cmp.instance.someinput = this.someinput;

     // @Output()
     cmp.instance.someoutput.subscribe(res => { this.consoleLog(res) })

     // Trigger change detection
     cmp.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges();

    // return data
    return cmp

})
```

I now want to feed new value to "someinput" variable, is this possible or I need to reinitialize the whole component again?!

Comment: You're not supposed to use loadAsRoot. Use loadNextToLocation or loadIntoLocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the reference to the component

```
compRef:ComponentRef;

someFunc() {
  this.dcl.loadAsRoot(SomeComponent, "#somediv", this.injector).then((cmp)=>{
    this.compRef = cmp;
    ...
  }
}

someOtherFunc() {
  this.compRef.someInput = 'someotherValue';
  this.compRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector
      .ref.detectChange‌​s();
}
```

Comment: Good, you just forgot the:
this.compRef.location.internalElement.parentView.changeDetector.ref.detectChanges();